# Perl copying specific lines of VECT File

Tags: perl, file, file-io, scripting, vector-graphics

I want to copy lines 7-12 of files, like
[this example `.vect` file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSvDj.png),
into another `.vect` file in the same directory.

I want each line, to be copied twice, and the two copies of each line to be pasted consecutively in the new file.

This is the code I have used so far, and would like to continue using these methods/packages in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

# This method works for reading a single file
my $dir = "D:\\Downloads";

my $readfile  = $dir ."\\2290-00002.vect";
my $writefile = $dir . "\\file2.vect";

#open a file to read
open(DATA1, "<". $readfile) or die "Can't open '$readfile': $!";;

# Open a file to write
open(DATA2, ">" . $writefile) or die "Can't open '$writefile': $!";;

# Copy data from one file to another.
while ( <DATA1> ) {
    print DATA2 $_;
}

close( DATA1 );
close( DATA2 );
```

What would be a simple way to do this using the same opening and closing file syntax I have used above?

Answer (score 2):

Just modify the `print` line to

```
print DATA2 $_, $_ if 7 .. 12;
```

See [Range Operators in "perlop - Perl operators and precedence"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) for details.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! This will help a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It's worth remembering the
[`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File)
module which maps a file line by line to a Perl array and allows you to manipulate text files using simple array operations. It can be slow when working with large amounts of data, but it is ideal for the majority of applications involving regular text files

Copying a range of lines from one file to another becomes a simple matter of copying an array slice. Remember that the file starts with line one in array element zero, so lines 7 to 12 are at indexes 6...11

This is the Perl code to do what you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

chdir 'D:\Downloads' or die $!;

tie my @infile,  'Tie::File', '2290-00002.vect' or die $!;
tie my @outfile, 'Tie::File', 'file2.vect' or die $!;

@outfile = map { $_, $_ } @infile[6..11];
```

Nothing else is required. Isn't that neat?